# Conditional column based on unique values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a table like this.

| ID | Classification_ID | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 10 | A |
| 1001 | 10 | B |
| 1002 | NULL | A |

Based on the `classification_ID`, I create `Cat_1_Count` and `Cat_2_Count` columns as:

```
SELECT ID, Location
CASE
    WHEN Classification_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS Cat_1_Count
CASE
    WHEN Classification_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS Cat_2_Count
FROM Table1
```

However, In addition to the condition on Classification_ID, I want to have Cat_1_Count or Cat_2_Count columns to be set to 1, for unique ID numbers, regardless of the Location. So what I want is results like this,

| ID | Classification_ID | Location | Cat_1_count | Cat_2_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 10 | A | 1 | 0 |
| 1001 | 10 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 1002 | NULL | A | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Your description of the conditional logic does not really correlate with your expected results.  Can you explain why the "Cat_1_count" and "Cat_2_count" values actually appear as 1 or 0 in your table of expected results?  (In fact, I think it you can explain the logic behind your expected results to all of us here, then you'll probably be well on your way to defining the logic that will need to go into your SELECT statement)

Comment: How to create Cat_1_count and Cat_2_count columns based on classification_ID but also considering whether the ID column is unique or not. So, in the above results table  where the ID is the same in the first two rows, I only want Cat_1_count to be displayed as having value 1 in only one of those two rows

Comment: @Craig Sorry there was an error in the initial CASE statement which I corrected now.

Comment: @sam_rox - why does the 1001 ID not have a "Cat_2_count" value also?  And why does the 1002 ID not have a "Cat_1_count" value?

Comment: @Craig Because 1001 has Classification_ID of 10, which is not null. Therefore Cat_1_Count is 1 and as it is not null Cat_2_count is 0. For 1002. as Classification_ID is null, Cat_2_count is 1 and as it is Null Cat_1_count is 0

Comment: Oh, that's my bad - I just missed that bit in the CASE.  Makes sense

Comment: Why the `Cat_1_count` is `0` for the second row ?

Comment: @Squirrel That is the result I am trying to get. Because the first and second rows have the same ID, I only want them to be counted once in Cat_1_Count. So second_row is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to identify the row. Add the condition to the case expression.

```
SELECT ID, Location,
    CASE
      WHEN Classification_ID IS NOT NULL 
      AND  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Location) = 1
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0
      END AS Cat_1_Count,
    CASE
      WHEN Classification_ID IS NULL 
      AND  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Location) = 1
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0
      END AS Cat_2_Count
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired output modified condition for `Cat_1_Count`.

```
SELECT ID, Location,
  CASE WHEN Classification_ID IS NOT NULL AND  
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Location) = 1
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
    END AS Cat_1_Count,
  CASE WHEN Classification_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Cat_2_Count
FROM Table1
```